# Populating dynamic html elements on validation failure in Laravel 5.1

Tags: php, validation, laravel, laravel-5, laravel-5.1

In my form, I am populating state and city dropdowns using ajax.
Also, on the same form the user can add multiple employees by clicking on the "Add more button".

In both above scenarios the HTML DOM elements are generated using jquery.

I need re-build the dynamically generated elements in case the validation fails on form submit.

Can anyone please tell me a right approach for achieving the above mentioned issue.

Thanks.

Comment: Before form submission you should validate all possible scenario using Jquery. So after submission you won't be get any issue.

Comment: I am doing it already. I am looking for server side validaion also.

Comment: If you will do server side validation you have to put additional work with front end.

Comment: Hi Yash, do you know any package that can be used to work with JS in Laravel. Like a JS helper or something like that.

Comment: You will get many option if you search, Check [this](https://github.com/proengsoft/laravel-jsvalidation) link for validation.

Comment: Thanks. I will definitely have a look at the link you provided.

Answer (score 5):

Say you've generated a list of inputs dynamically by calling a js function, maybe something like

```
//JS
function generate(){
  $("#container-abc").append("<input name=name[]>");
}
```

---

```
<!--HTML -->
<input name=name[] />
<input name=name[] />
```

Submit them and if there's validation error you will get back the values using:

```
//in your blade
$name = Request::old('name');
@if(count($name) > 0)
  for (var i = 1; i <= {{count($name)}}; i++) {
    generate();
  }
@endif
```

Comment: This seems like a feasible solution. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

you can use

```
return Redirect::back()->withInput();
```

or for more info visit https://laravel.com/docs/5.2/requests#old-input

> Old Input
>
> Laravel allows you to keep input from one request during the next
>   request. This feature is particularly useful for re-populating forms
>   after detecting validation errors. However, if you are using Laravel's
>   included validation services, it is unlikely you will need to manually
>   use these methods, as some of Laravel's built-in validation facilities
>   will call them automatically. Flashing Input To The Session
>
> The flash method on the Illuminate\Http\Request instance will flash
>   the current input to the session so that it is available during the
>   user's next request to the application:
>
> $request->flash();
>
> You may also use the flashOnly and flashExcept methods to flash a
>   sub-set of the request data into the session:
>
> $request->flashOnly(['username', 'email']);
>
> $request->flashExcept('password');
>
> Flash Input Into Session Then Redirect
>
> Since you often will want to flash input in association with a
>   redirect to the previous page, you may easily chain input flashing
>   onto a redirect using the withInput method:
>
> return redirect('form')->withInput();
>
> return redirect('form')->withInput($request->except('password'));
>
> Retrieving Old Data
>
> To retrieve flashed input from the previous request, use the old
>   method on the Request instance. The old method provides a convenient
>   helper for pulling the flashed input data out of the session:
>
> $username = $request->old('username');
>
> Laravel also provides a global old helper function. If you are
>   displaying old input within a Blade template, it is more convenient to
>   use the old helper. If no old input exists for the given string, null
>   will be returned: